# Is there any way I should have asked my question differently?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So about two weeks ago I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054417/unity3d-exported-game-differs-from-editor) on Stack Overflow about a problem I have with (what I think is) a bug in Unity when exporting my game. I really thought I had asked my question as clearly as possible, but I'm not really getting any response.

So did I ask my question with too little information, or is the question unclear?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you think there's a bug in a product you should be submitting a bug report to that company.  SO isn't a bug tracker.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I actually hadn't thought about that yet!

Comment: I think it's likely that no one who's looked at the question has had the same issue and thus can't provide a solution.

Comment: Unless someone has had a similar problem I don't think that's answerable. If you can create a minimal example that exhibits your behavior I'd definitely open a bug report with the Unity folks.

Comment: @Will That's the thing, I don't have a clue on how someone possibly could reproduce the problem.

Comment: Cut out everything from your application except for that start screen and see if it still repos.

Comment: @Will Alright will try that, thanks for your replies anyway!

Comment: What do you think has a higher chance. a) There is a simple mistake somewhere and you don't know where to look. b) You being the one to find a really visible and fundamental bug in a product used by many people and in many games, ranging from the simple to the multimillion dollar AAA title. The more logical option is a), but you're not showing anything that might allow people to assist with that. Namely: there is a referral to code that is involved but no code is present in the question.

Comment: @Gimby That's right as well! Guess I'll have to cut out a lot of unnecessary code to only show the parts that have anything to do with it though

Comment: Most code questiond should have a [mcve]. Although that follows from basic debugging principles.